# Create a new login that will return JSON data without changing the current ASP.NET MVC login mechanism

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm working on an existing project that has the below code in the `Startup.Auth.cs` file.

However, some users will login to the system using Web API. So, I need to create a new login that will authenticate the user and return their data via JSON. How do I go about this without recreating my login mechanism?

```cs
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your current code snippet:

```
//Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

So the complete code should look like this

```
public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

public partial class Startup
{
// For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });            
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    PublicClientId = "self";
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };

    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean on the same function, or create a new one?

Comment: Also, what are the types of `PublicClientId` and `OAuthOptions` variables? 
`ApplicationOAuthProvider` cannot be found.

Comment: If you also control the JS application accessing the WebAPI, you could (upon detecting the 403 response), redirect the user to a "blank" page in the MVC application and then redirect them to the start page of the JS application.

Comment: find more information here [link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864)